# Interactive Service Desktop not working as expected on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

With **Windows Server *2012*** it was possible to use an application running on the **Interactive Service Desktop**. The service was configured to **"Allow service to interact with desktop"**.

Starting the "Interactive Service Detection" service I was able to switch to the interactive desktop and to use the application GUI. ([Trouble with interactive service on Windows Server 2012](https://serverfault.com/questions/674120/trouble-with-interactive-service-on-windows-server-2012) is already fixed.)

**Now, on Windows Server *2016***, the Interactive Service Desktop does not work anymore as expected. Different test system have different behaviors: Either the Interactive Desktop is simply black or the application GUI is visible but cannot be used (no mouse no keyboard).

I guess, it is not allowed anymore to control the application, you can just view it.

**Is there any setting (registry or similar) to allow full application interaction on Windows Server 2016 in Interactive Service Desktop?**

Answer (score 1):

Session 0 control has been disabled in Server 2016/Windows 10. This is meant as a security feature, but the exact reason is unknown.

However there are two possible workarounds, either by installing a [driver](https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/discussions/topics/4000336153), which restores the functionality, or by [setting up TightVNC](https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000106824-keyboard-and-mouse-does-not-work-on-session-0-on-windows-10-server-2016) (or another distribution of VNC) to allow remote usage.

Both workarounds put the system at risk, if you want so. Using unsigned drivers allows installation of other unsigned drivers and VNC is unencrypted desktop transfer, althrough encrypted communication is available in some implementations.

Comment: You need to include the substance of the linked-to content to guard against link rot

Comment: @Colt: I Hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

Windows + R or Run...

regedit

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Windows

Open NoInteractiveServices

Change value to ZERO

Close window and restart the service you want to interact with.

Comment: Please read my question. The problem is NOT to start the UI0Detect service, but that the service is not running as in earlier Windows versions.